# Decode chirping frequency with uC at center frequency of around 100kHz

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, sampling, frequency-measurement

## Context

For my MSc project I'm building a chirping signal (a bit like LoRa) with a center frequency of 100 kHz. For now, the bandwidth is 10 kHz such that I have around 10 periods per chip. For ease, my transmitter is transmitting four different frequencies only (SF = 2) for 10 periods and then moves on to the next frequency within the 10 kHz bandwidth around 100 kHz.

It is all very basic setup but that is not the main point. What I'd like to achieve is decoding with another uC (microcontroller).

Right now, I am using an ESP32 to measure time in us (microseconds) between peaks (pulses) in each of the 10 periods a frequency is sent. This time is averaged to get the frequency of those pulses estimated. My goal is to be able to decode signals with a center frequency of 100 kHz but at the moment, only 1 kHz is what I can achieve. In the end, I would like to move from a square wave with pulses to sine waves, but I could use hardware (schmitt trigger) to convert sine wave into square wave just to be able to use gpio interrupts on an uC as I do now.

## Problem

The thing is that for 1 kHz, the time between a pulse is 1000 us and the difference between the frequencies in us is large enough to distinguish. However, when the center frequency increases, of course the time between pulses decreases linearly and so 100 kHz only has 10us between pulses. Measuring time between pulses often is not accurate enough and the difference between frequencies becomes vague. Meaning, some pulses are measured to have 11us or 9us between them while they should have 10us between them. The transmitted signal is very stable which I confirmed with the oscilloscope.

## Question

What would be a smart way to clearly obtain the different frequencies (> 2 different frequencies) with an uC and also being able to do some other computation such as calculating which data is coded into those chirps.

- could I use an RF mixer, if so, what would I achieve with that / how will it work. are my frequencies high enough to do so?
- Is there another smart way of obtaining the different frequencies?
- Any other suggestions / tips / tricks?
- should I just use an FPGA?

Comment: "Measuring time between pulses often is not accurate enough" It isn't clear why this isn't accurate enough. Assuming this is correctly done with an input capture timer triggering on signal edge.

Comment: You are right, I altered the question to show why it is vague. In a sense, when a pulse should have 10us between them, they often vary between 9us and 11 us and thus, with a 10kHz bandwidth it becomes hard to distinguish the different frequencies.

Comment: So put some acceptance margin in the software? And also what clock source your MCU has is very relevant. If you run on some internal one, that's perhaps not accurate enough for your needs.

Comment: This is not a trvial task - but it's a common task. Please have a look around: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing in combination with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis . Please also give https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation a shot. Enjoy the Math! =)